# UIMA ruta Get a part of input number

Tags: uima, ruta

I have a input number(ex.01234567 and 98765432) and i need to get  45(from first) and 54(from second) to annotation MM, it is 5 and 6 position. How to make this in UIMA ruta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE MM;
NUM->{"....(..)"-> 1 = MM;};
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*